# Evaluating $\frac{(1+i)^{n+2}}{(1-i)^n}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Evaluate $\dfrac{(1+i)^{n+2}}{(1-i)^n}$

I think that the meaning is that it need to be simplified.
Thanks

Comment: *Hint:* $\dfrac{1+i}{1-i} = \dfrac{2i}{(1-i)(1+i)} = i$, $(1+i)^2 = 2i$.

Comment: So because the two expressions are in the power of n, the result will include (1-i)power 2n?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question, but
$$\dfrac{(1+i)^{n+2}}{(1-i)^n} = \left(\dfrac{1+i}{1-i}\right)^n\cdot(1+i)^2.$$

Comment: What I mean is that $\dfrac{(1+i)^{n+2}}{(1-i)^n}$ needs to be multiple by is z* or $\dfrac{(1+i)^{n}}{(1+i)^n}$
That gives $\dfrac{(1+i)^{2n+2}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{(1+i)^{n+2}}{(1-i)^n}=\frac{2i(1+i)^n}{(1-i)^n}=2i\frac{(1+i)^n}{(1-i)^n}=2i(-i)^{-n}=2ie^{\frac{1}{2}\pi in}$$

Answer (score -1):

This simplifies to $2 i^{n+1}$.

Comment: The OP is probably more interested in the process of the simplification- not just the final answer.