# Calculate $\frac {(1 +i)^n}{(1-i)^{n-2}}$ where $n$ is an integer such that $n\ge2$

Tags: complex-numbers

Calculate $\frac {(1 +i)^n}{(1-i)^{n-2}}$ where $n$ is an integer such that $n\ge2$

[Evaluating $\frac{(1+i)^{n+2}}{(1-i)^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540789/evaluating-frac1in21-in) Is very similar to this one; actually, with the information given in this problem i got that:

$$\frac {(1 +i)^n}{(1-i)^{n-2}} = -2i^{n+1}$$

But evaluating at $n=4$ and $n=5$ the results are different. I’d really appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: What is $\frac{1+i}{1-i}$?

Comment: $\frac {1+ i}{1-i} = i$

Comment: What do you mean "the results are different"? What do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: Using the polar representation, $(\sqrt2)^{n-n+2}\text{cis}\left(n\frac\pi4+(n-2)\frac\pi4\right)$.

Comment: I get $\frac{2}{i}$ and I expect $-2i$ when $n=4$

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{i}=-i$.

Comment: @M.P. I didn’t notice that, thank you, that’s what I was missing.

Comment: If u multiply both , denominator and numerator, by $(1+i)$ then you would get $i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is absolutely right

$\frac {(1+ i )^4}{(1-i )^2}=\frac {(2i )^2}{-2i}= \frac{-4}{-2i}=\frac {2}{i} = \frac{2i}{i^2} = -2i$

$-2i^{4+1} =-2i^{5} $

$$i^4 = 1$$

So $-2i^{5}=-2i$

Comment: I checked for $n=5$ answer is absolutely correct !!

Comment: Hope this helps :)

Comment: Man, if you think I helped you then you should upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

As Octavio Berlanga noted,
$\frac {1+ i}{1-i} 
=\frac {i(1+ i)}{i(1-i)} 
=\frac {i(1+ i)}{i+1} 
= i
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\frac {(1 +i)^n}{(1-i)^{n-2}}
&=\frac {(1 +i)^{n-2}(1+i)^2}{(1-i)^{n-2}}\\
&=i^{n-2}(1+2i-1)\\
&=i^{n-2}(2i)\\
&=2i^{n-1}\\
&=2(-i, 1, i, -1, \text{repeated starting at 0})\\
\end{array}
$